# error: expected primary-expression before 'int' on the terminal of my vscode

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner, it doesn't seem to have an error on the code. But when I try to run it, on the terminal it says that I had to put expected primary-expression before 'int'..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int a = 1;
    cout << a << endl;
    cout << sizeof(a) << " byte" << endl;
    cout << numeric_limits<int>::max() << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `#include <limits>`

you need to add the header file to use it

Comment: I wanted to show the 'long' value but it still shows the int value

Comment: long value of what, the a variable?